# Invalid JDBC escape syntax at line position 22 '=' character expected. with Guidewire

Tags: jtds, guidewire, sql-server-2016-localdb

I am trying to use SQL Server Express LocalDB with Guidewire Studio which is basically an adjusted version of IntelliJ (for those of you who know it).
I am able to use the database tool to connect to my instance with:

`jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://./databaseName;instance=pipeName;namedPipe=true`.

jtds driver version is 1.3.1

But when I try to start the server I get:

`ERROR Server.Database Error setting connection context: Invalid JDBC escape syntax at line position 22 '=' character expected.`

I don't know if it is fixable, but I thought I will put it out there in case someone using Guidewire has run into the same issue.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace. The error suggests the problem is not with connecting itself, but with executing a statement with a JDBC escape. Given jTDS development stopped somewhere around 2013 or so, and only provides JDBC 3.0 support, it does not support all modern JDBC features, which might be part of the problem (or you're simply using an invalid JDBC escape).

Comment: It looks indeed that the problem is the jtds driver itself. I don't have to the code creating the connection. Is there a new jtds-like out there which can work with newer JDBC features? I read somewhere that the jtds driver itself cannot handle store procedure.

Comment: You don't mention what version of the GW apps you're using, but many people use PostgreSQL as a local DB, and generally the H2 "Quickstart" option is functional also.